# Aggregate an array of dicts based on value

Tags: python

### Revision

```
data = [[{'type': 'low', 'count': 100}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': 45}, {'type': 'high', 'count': 5}],
[{'type': 'medium', 'count': 45}, {'type': 'high', 'count': 5}],
[{'type': 'low', 'count': 100}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': 45}]]

def unique_type(data):
    result = []
    type_list = []
    for x in data:
      for y in x: # arrays of dict
          if y['type'] not in type_list: #iterate through dicts in array
              type_list.append(y['type']) #if not type in list
              result.append({'type': y['type'], 'count': []}) #add type in list
    return result, type_list

result, type_list = unique_type(data)
empty_results = result
for arr in data:
    
    for num in range(0, len(type_list)):
        try:
            number = 0
            while number < len(type_list):
                print(f"{arr[num]['type']} == {result[number]['type']}")
                if arr[num]['type'] == result[number]['type']:
                    result[number]['count'].append(arr[num]['count'])
                    number += 1
                    break
                else:
                    number += 1
        except IndexError:
    
            # TODO need some way for evaluating if a key is missing from arr compared to result**
    
            print(f"Index Error{result[number]['type']}")
                
            result[number]['count'].append(float('nan'))
```

#### Results I get

```
[{'type': 'low', 'count': [100, nan, 100, nan]}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': [45, 45, 45]}, {'type': 'high', 'count': [5, 5]}]
```

#### Results desired

```
[{'type': 'low', 'count': [100, nan, 100]}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': [45, 45, 45]}, {'type': 'high', 'count': [5, 5, nan]}]
```

`Unique_type()`
allows me to iterate through my array of dictionaries and create an array of unique keys

`results`
allows me to build my desired array of dictionaries

When iterating over the array of dictionaries, I want to ensure that there is a value whether or not that key exits in results.

### Original Post

Hey folks im building out a model thats been a little tricky for me

```
    a = {'type': 'Low', 'count': 184} 
    b = {'type': 'Low', 'count': 186} 
    c = {'type': 'Low', 'count': 97}

 

    new = [a,b,c]

### how do i accomplish below?

    result = {'type': low, 'count': [184, 186, 97]}
```

Comment: That depends. Can there be other `type`s as well? What happens then? And what have you tried so far? Also, it might help to have context explaining why you need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [[{'type': 'low', 'count': 100}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': 45}, {'type': 'high', 'count': 5}],
        [{'type': 'medium', 'count': 45}, {'type': 'high', 'count': 5}],
        [{'type': 'low', 'count': 100}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': 45}]]


def get_all_types(dicts):
    types = set()
    for i in dicts:
        if i['type'] not in types:
            types.add(i['type'])
    return types


def multiple(dicts, types):
    finaldicts = []
    for i in types:
        dic = {'type': i, 'count': []}
        for j in dicts:
            if j['type'] == i:
                if type(j['count']) == list:
                    if  len(j['count'])>0:
                        dic['count'].extend(j['count'])
                    else:
                        dic['count'].append("nan")
                else:
                    dic['count'].append(j['count'])
        finaldicts.append(dic)
    return finaldicts


new_dics_with_types_aggregate = []
types = set()
for dicts in data:
    types = types.union(get_all_types(dicts))

for dicts in data:
    new_dics_with_types_aggregate.extend(multiple(dicts,types))
print(types)
print(new_dics_with_types_aggregate)

print(multiple(new_dics_with_types_aggregate,types))
```

Output

```
{'low', 'medium', 'high'}
[{'type': 'low', 'count': [100]}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': [45]}, {'type': 'high', 'count': [5]}, {'type': 'low', 'count': []}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': [45]}, {'type': 'high', 'count': [5]}, {'type': 'low', 'count': [100]}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': [45]}, {'type': 'high', 'count': []}]
[{'type': 'low', 'count': [100, 'nan', 100]}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': [45, 45, 45]}, {'type': 'high', 'count': [5, 5, 'nan']}]
```

Comment: I like you solution here, thank you! How would you apply this to my new use case above. @Danish Bansal

Comment: beautiful work, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic solution, assuming you can have several types:

```
from itertools import groupby

[{'type': k, 'count': [i['count'] for i in g]}
 for k,g in groupby(sorted(new, key=lambda d: d['type']),
                    key=lambda d: d['type'])
]
```

input:

```
[{'type': 'Low', 'count': 184},
 {'type': 'Low', 'count': 186},
 {'type': 'Low', 'count': 97},
 {'type': 'High', 'count': 1000}]
```

output:

```
[{'type': 'High', 'count': [1000]},
 {'type': 'Low', 'count': [184, 186, 97]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have just 'low' you can use this, otherwise you would need to change it around to be more modular

```py
a = {'type': 'Low', 'count': 184} 
b = {'type': 'Low', 'count': 186} 
c = {'type': 'Low', 'count': 97}
new = [a,b,c]
result = {'type':'Low', 'count':[]}


for i in new:
    if i['type'] == 'Low':
        result['count'].append(i['count'])
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {'type': 'Low', 'count': 184} 
b = {'type': 'Low', 'count': 186} 
c = {'type': 'Low', 'count': 97}
d = {'type': 'High', 'count': 102}
e = {'type': 'High', 'count': 142}
new = [a,b,c,d,e]

result = []
type_list = []
for x in new:
    if x['type'] not in type_list:
        type_list.append(x['type'])
        result.append({'type': x['type'], 'count': [x['count']]})
    else:
        result[type_list.index(x['type'])]['count'].append(x['count'])
print(result)
```

output :

```
[
    {'type': 'Low', 'count': [184, 186, 97]},
    {'type': 'High', 'count': [102, 142]}
]
```

**Updated answer :**

```
data = [[{'type': 'low', 'count': 100}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': 45}, {'type': 'high', 'count': 5}], [{'type': 'medium', 'count': 45}, {'type': 'high', 'count': 5}], [{'type': 'low', 'count': 100}, {'type': 'medium', 'count': 45}]] 

type_list = []
[type_list.append(item["type"]) for sublist in data for item in sublist if item["type"] not in type_list]
print(type_list)

result = [] 
for type in type_list:
    result.append({'type': type, 'count': []}) 
    for sublist in data:
        for type in type_list:
            if type not in [item['type'] for item in sublist]:
                result[type_list.index(type)]['count'].append(None)
            else:
                x = [item['count'] for item in sublist if item['type'] == type][0]
                result[type_list.index(type)]['count'].append(x)
print(result)
```

Output :

```
['low', 'medium', 'high']
[
    {'type': 'low', 'count': [100, None, 100]}, 
    {'type': 'medium', 'count': [45, 45, 45]}, 
    {'type': 'high', 'count': [5, 5, None]}
]
```

Comment: thank you this worked nicely for the original use case

Comment: could you take a look at my modified use case. Ive included more details 
@patate1684

Comment: Yes i will update my answer with the new info soon :)

Comment: Thank you soo much, ive ben struggling on this hard and would really appreciate your help. Also very curious to see you solution @patate1684

Comment: Updated ! Tell me what you think ;)

Comment: Thank you this works for my specific use case!